# Display a link only if user is an admin

Tags: php, authentication

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to make a registration form only for an admin(no need for other users). I want to show one of the menu nav ("Add photo") only to admins.

LOGIN.php:

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';

    $username = "Efren";
    $password = "111";

    if (($_POST['txt_uname_email'] == $username)&& ($_POST['txt_password'] == $password)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['admin_is_logged'] = true;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("homepage.php","_self");</script>';            
    }
```

This is the part of the header that I am trying to show only to admins:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['admin_is_logged']) && $_SESSION['admin_is_logged'] == true){
        echo '<li><a href="/addnew.php">add photo</a></li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Right now “add photo” is hidden both to admin and other visitors.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` check this before condition

Comment: Does your form post the POST data 'txt_uname_email' ans 'txt_password' correctly? Does the condition resolve to true? btw Efren is not an email (txt_uname_email)

Comment: Are these code snippets on different pages? If so you'll need to start the session with `session_start()` on each page you want to use the session on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start session on every page you want access to `$_SESSION` variable. I saw your `session_start` is inside if statement. Just set it on top of every file (where you need session) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
session_start();
```

on file beginning just after `<?php`

Comment: Thank you, it  does help!))